# R: read connection until a given character is found

Tags: r, file

In R, Is it possible to read a connection (or just a file) until a given character is found?

I am looking for something similar to `std::getline(io, str, '\t')`

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately neither `readLines` nor `scan` can be made to do this without reading either the whole file or manually searching for the delimiter. So you need to use either `readChar` or `readLines`, and manually search for the delimiter. Or you use `scan(io, sep = '\t')[1]` but that will read the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read characters one by one through a file connection until a given character is found.

If your purpose is just to find the text up to the first occurrence of a particular character (and you don't care so much about the speed), you can use `readLines`, `regexpr`, and `substr` like this:

```
filename <- "2DArray.cpp"

filestring <- ""
for (i in readLines(filename)) {
  indexCharInLine <- as.integer(regexpr(":",i))
  if (indexCharInLine > 0) {
    filestring <- paste0(filestring, substr(i, 1, indexCharInLine))
    break
  }
  filestring <- paste0(filestring,i)
}
```

You will get the result:

```
> filestring
[1] "// Two-Dimensional Dynamic Array#include <iostream>using namespace std;typedef int* IntArrayPtr;int main(){  int d1, d2;  cout << \"Enter the row and col dims of the array:"
```

Note that this does not show the special newline characters.

Comment: Your code is reading the while file twice, which is extremely inefficient. It should be much more efficient to paste the `readLines` result into one string. Alternatively, don’t paste it and scan the lines separately.